# Relink all the edges of a vertex Neo4j/Neptune

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

How can I refresh all the edges from a vertex?

Use case:

I have to link different entities provided by some logic and the linking needs to be refreshed periodically. One way is to delete the previous edges and then create a new ones inside a transaction, but this solution wouldn't work for a large graph since there would be large transaction running which will impact other things.

Can someone suggest other way around for graphdb like Neo4j and Neptune?

Comment: Is there a finer-grained strategy maybe? What needs to be updated exactly?
Also, is all your data interconnected? Can it be split into several independent groups?

Comment: Typically how many edges will need to be updated and how many vertices will be involved?